# How to remove old Anaconda paths in order to work with Miniconda

Tags: python, path, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, miniconda

I installed and uninstalled Anaconda to use Miniconda instead. My goal is to use it with Python 3.7 and Jupyter Notebooks (on OX 10.95). When I now run Jupyter the kernel does not work because it keeps on referring to an old Ananconda path. I do not know how to remove it. See below the paths with anaconda3 should be removed from this:

```
(base) air-van-lotte:~ lsluyser$ conda activate venv1 
(venv1) air-van-lotte:~ lsluyser$ echo $PATH 
/Users/lsluyser/Downloads/ENTER/bin:/Users/lsluyser/miniconda3/envs/venv1/bin:/Users/lsluyser/miniconda3/condabin:~/anaconda3/bin:/anaconda3/bin:/Users/lsluyser/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin 
(venv1) air-van-lotte:~ lsluyser$
```

Can you advise how to remove it? Please be as specific as possible because I do not have a programming background. I cannot find online examples that are applicable. 
Thanks a million in advance! Lotte

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Stackoverflow.

When you install Anaconda it tells you at the end of the install something like "now add the following line to the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`
file in your home directory."

If you don't use the Bash shell then you may need to look in some other file, but you get the idea. In those files you will find line that read:

```
export PATH=<some value>:$PATH
```

Again the syntax might be different according to shell, but the purpose of each such line is to put a new entry at the beginning of your shell's search path - the list of places it looks for executable files. You appear to have multiple such lines in those initialisation files, because many entries are duplicate in your `$PATH` setting.

Duplicate entries do absolutely no good, and threaten to lurk around when their duplicates have been removed, leaving your shell still finding executables from that directory. Once you have rationalised this by removing duplicates you should then re-order the statements to put the `PATH` entries in your required order of preference.

If you aren't sure how the `$PATH` setting affects your shell [this article](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8207/14f/notes/400_search_path.html) is a fairly approachable explanation to what's going on, and [this article it links](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8207/14f/notes/320_shell_variables.html#appending-to-a-variable) talks about extending the path.